# Radio Button field not outputting anything

Tags: fieldtype, bug

I am having a very odd issue. This is on EE 2.8.1. I created a channel and within that channel I have a radio button field with the values of Yes or No. I can create entries and check the correct option. If I check in the database, it has the correct values for that field for the entry I created.

Within a template I try some code like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" dynamic="no"}
  <div>{title} - {my_radio_button_field}</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And the output is just: Entry title - 
It seems to just output a blank space for the radio button field value, it is parsing it so it recognized the field name, but it is not getting the value for output.

The only weird thing that happened was I originally had it as a checkbox and changed to a radio button, so to alleviate that I created a second field as a radio button with the same options and it behaves the same.

I have seen a ton of examples (and used identical code myself in the past) using the field just like this or in a conditional. And all the data is being recorded properly in the DB, so I am sort of out of ideas? Can anyone suggest some things to try?

UPDATE: What I found is that if any of the entries don't have a value for that radio button, then they all will display as empty. When I limited the entries down to entries with a value selected it works. This seems like a bug to me, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting that custom field, and recreating the custom field as a radio first. That may fix the issue.